# Suitable hash function for matrix sparsity pattern

Tags: c++, hash, hashmap, sparse-matrix, unordered-map

I am working with sparse matrices stored in a general sparse format (compressed row). I.e. I store the matrix:

```
0 x y 0
0 0 0 0 
z 0 0 0
```

in the form of:

- Matrix dimensions:  [3,4]
- The offset of each row: [0,2,2,3]
- The column of each nonzero entry: [1,2,0]
- Nonzero elements:        [x,y,z]

I am looking for hash function which would allow me to "cache" the sparsity patterns (i.e. the first three vectors with integers above). For that I suppose that I need a good hash function that I can supply to the hash map implementation I was planning to use, namely C++'s `std::unordered_map`.

Does anyone have some tips on how to find a good hash function for a problem like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSR representation is unique per matrix, i.e. the nonzero elements appear in left-to-right, top-to-bottom order, then you can hash all the vectors and combine the hashes using [`boost::hash_combine`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/doc/html/hash_combine.html) (if you don't want a dependency on Boost, just copy-paste it, it's very short).

Comment: Great tip about the `boost::hash_combine`. I will look into it. My nonzero elements are indeed ordered like you suggest.